# Are there any particular integers we are certain to arrive at by repeated application of $\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$ on any positive integer $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we pick an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, and repeatedly apply the operation $\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$ on it. We are guaranteed to eventually reach $0$, but are there any other small integers we are certain to reach before we get to $0$?

Ideally, I'd like to derive a minimal set $S=\{x \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$, where for any initial $n$, we are guaranteed to get a member of $S$ if we keep applying the operation.

Comment: Since only $1$ and $2$ map to $0$, you're guaranteed to hit one of them. But, for example, $n=3$ does not hit $2$, and $n=5$ does not hit $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood: if, as you say, "it is guaranted" you eventually reach zero, isn't $\;S=\{0\}\; $ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo: right, we are guaranteed to reach 0, but I'm interested in any other, larger-than-zero integers we are guaranteed to arrive at. I'll edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: @Mathmo123: that's a good, simple way to think about it. I suppose if I can prove that I will eventually hit 0, then by this logic I must have hit either 1 or 2 right before. This is a good answer to my question, though now I wonder: how do I **prove** I will eventually hit 0?

Comment: It is a bounded monotonic decreasing sequence.  Every bounded monotonic sequence has a limit.  Every term greater than zero will map to something strictly less than it.

Comment: OK, I think my question is now answered. Seems I just need to prove that I will eventually get 0, then I can "work backwards" to show that I must have either 1 or 2 right before I got to zero, then keep branching: for example, to get 1 I must have gotten either 3 or 4 before, to get 2 I must have gotten either 5 or 6... In fact it's an infinite tree where each level is twice the size of its predecessor. Pretty neat. Thanks!